# Swift make an object with Apple's Object conform to Codable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

Currently I have a model class like:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String? = nil
    var location: CLLocation? = nil
}
```

But then Swift is telling me that:

```
Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

And I understand that it's because of `CLLocation` not conforming to `Codable` protocol, is there any way to workaround this?

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/@kf99916/codable-nsmanagedobject-and-cllocation-in-swift-4-b32f042cb7d3) is a suggestion how to make a CLLocation Decodable.

Comment: And [here's an explanation](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-you-cant-make-someone-elses-class-decodable-a-long-winded-explanation-of-required-initializers/6437) of why making someone else's class `Decodable` is not possible directly

Comment: Thank you both, it's been of great help both articles linked

Comment: @NewDev very cool link, thanks for pointing to it